# Disable end time in timepicker upto where start time is selected

Tags: jquery, timepicker

I've a jQuery timepicker component for storing start time, like

```
$("#startTimePicker").timepicker({

        showOn : "both",
        buttonImage : "UX_Common/images/icon_timepicker.png",
        buttonImageOnly : true,
        ampm : true,
        stepMinute : 5,

    });
```

and another one for storing end time, like

```
$("#endTimePicker").timepicker({

        showOn : "both",
        buttonImage : "UX_Common/images/icon_timepicker.png",
        buttonImageOnly : true,
        ampm : true,
        stepMinute : 5,

    });
```

I need the validation like end time should not come before to the start time. What I need to do for that? Pls help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried examples on this [page](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) and [jQuery docs](http://haineault.com/media/jquery/ui-timepickr/page/)?

Comment: The one given  in " http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ "
contains both datetimepicker. But I'm using timepicker only